# Chartjs year markings

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When I make a Chartjs table the background is a plain square pattern. What I would like is to be able to mark the transition from one year to the next with a bolder vertical line at every new year.

In the below example chart, I have 12 quarters. I would like to have a line appear between the Q1s and Q4s. Is this possible?

```js
chart_code = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
  labels: ['Q1 15','Q2 15','Q3 15','Q4 15','Q1 16','Q2 16','Q3 16','Q4 16','Q1 17','Q2 17','Q3 17','Q4 17'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Teststatistic',
    data: [50,40,30,20,50,20,10,10,10,40,30,80],
    backgroundColor: ['rgba(0, 105, 146, 1)'],
    borderColor: ['rgba(0, 105, 146, 1)'],
    borderWidth: 3,
    fill: false,
    pointStyle: 'rect',
    pointRadius: 5
  }]
},
options: {
  responsive: false,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
      boxWidth: 80,
      boxHeight: 80
    }
  },
  scales: {
    x: { 
      ticks: {
        maxRotation: 0, 
        minRotation: 0
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/grid.html

Comment: The problem with adjusting color of grid lines is that my final graph has a lot of data and many tickmarks are omitted due to lack of space. So the grid-lines I want to recolor are not in the final graph

Comment: Then you'll need to provide a reproducible example of the problem - the code in your question doesn't show the problem you're asking people to solve